# How to convert a Vimeo playlist into an array of video addresses?

Tags: javascript, video, embed, vimeo, playlist

I have a playlist (showcase) on Vimeo and I'd like to present the videos on my site but differently than how their 'embed' code does it. If possible I'd like to get to a point where I can query the playlist and generate an array of video links so I can apply my own styles and code to them.
Is this technically possible somehow?

Comment: Do you have a Vimeo Pro / Business account, if yes then you should find the links in your user panel. If not then you'll have to search an article on how it's done (**extract mp4 link from vimeo**). If you can practice for one link manually, you can later tell the machine how to do same result.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to handle all the UI yourself, but using the [Vimeo API](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/showcases#get_showcase_videos), you'll be able to get the list of Videos within the playlist (AKA Showcase).

You'd make a `GET` to `https://api.vimeo.com/albums/{album_id}/videos`. This will return you a list of `video` objects within the showcase. You can see all the fields on `video` in my link above.

But some options you could leverage (based on your need)

- `video.link`: The URL that you could put in the browser to get to your video on Vimeo.com
- `video.embed.html`: This is the HTML for a single `iframe` to your video (within the Vimeo Player). You could create your own "playlist" by stacking these embeds or laying them out however you want.
- `video.files[0].link`: A link to an actual mp4 file which you can do really whatever you want with. This is *only* available if you own the video (aka it belongs to the account that authenticated the API request you made)

Let me know if this was helpful - I'm happy to chat more in the comments.

Comment: I always get 422, even I'm the owner of the showcase. any solution?

Comment: You get a 422 when making a GET to the /albums endpoint? Are you making the request with an access token generated from developer.vimeo.com?

Comment: I'm not using any token, do you have code?

Comment: You need to generate an access token and then send it in the request header. The following link tells you how to generate it and the following section tells you how to send it in the header: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/guides/start#generate-access-token